# Trouble getting php data from database through javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

On my php site, I want to retrieve data every three seconds from a mysql database using javascript.

Problem: when I retrieve data using `SELECT * from msgtable`, then neither php nor javascript `startTime` seems to work.

**JavaScript:**

```
setInterval(function() {
   var link = document.getElementById("chg");
   link.href = "http://google.com.pk";
   link.innerHTML = "<?php  dynamic(); ?>"; 
}, 3000);

function startTime() {
   var today = new Date();
   var s = today.getSeconds();
   s = checkTime(s);

   if( s == s+3 ) { alert("faraz"); }
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML= s;
   t = setTimeout( function() { startTime() }, 500 );
}

function changeURL() {
   var link = document.getElementById("chg");
   link.href = "http://google.com.pk";
   link.innerHTML = "Google Pakistan"; 
}

function checkTime( i ) {
   if ( i < 10 ) {
      i = "0" + i;
   }
   return i;
}
```

**php:**

```
<?php 
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("msgs",$connection);  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM msgtable", $connection);

    function dynamic() {
        echo "faraz";

        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
        echo $row['msgBody'] ;
        }   
    }
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onLoad="startTime()">
    <div id="chg1"> 3 Seconds to Google Pakistan  </div>
    <a href="http://google.it" id="chg">Google Italia</a>
    <!-- Hafiz Faraz Mukhtar-->
    <div id="time"> Time </div>
    <div class="publicOut">Faraz</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/1331430

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a PHP function through JavaScript like this:

```
link.innerHTML = "<?php  dynamic(); ?>";
```

You will need to make an AJAX call to run the PHP script and return the result. I would recommend using jQuery and $.ajax, which makes this very easy.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: hhmm alrite. then why does it correctly echos "faraz"; in dynamic()? if we remove select and fetch array .

Comment: We can use  link.innerHTML = "<?php  dynamic(); ?>"; like this in javascript. i am sure.

Comment: It may echo 'faraz', but the JavaScript you posted above is not what's calling it. If you could post the whole code as well as the filenames, it will be easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: If you have that JavaScript inside a PHP script, then yes, you can write the syntax like that. When the page is parsed, the PHP tags will be removed before being sent to the browser.

Comment: this is the whole code sir. ok let me try it jQuery way. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Also, if you get the Firefox browser and also install the firebug addon, this will help you a whole lot because it allows you to monitor the AJAX requests and see the response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use normal ajax or jquery ajax for this .Use javascript setInterval() function for setting an interval

Here is a sample jquery ajax method

```
        function request()
         {
           $.ajax ({
           url : "";
           data : {},
           dataType : "" ,
           success : function(success) {} ,
           error : function() {}
           });
         }
```

**setInterval() Syntax**

```
     setInterval(request,3000);  // in milliseconds
```